# Why isn't this a tag clickable?

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

```
    {%if collection.title == "Meat"%}
{% if collection.image %}<div class="collection-image" style="background-image: url('{{ collection.image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}'); max-height:400px; "> {% endif %}
   <div class="collection-title text-center" style="padding: 50px 0;">
  <h1 class="collection-text--headline title text-center" style="margin-top:30px;">{{ collection.title }}</h1>
  {% if collection.description.size > 0 %}
  <div class="collection-text--body text-center rte large--three-fifths push--large--one-fifth">
    <h4>{{ collection.description }}</h4>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  </div>
  <div class="text-center" style="margin-top: -40px;
padding-bottom: 100px;">
<a href="http://www.greensburymarket.com/collections/all" class="btn     btn--large btn--splash uppercase sec-col-button" >Learn More</a>
</div>
  {% if collection.image %}<div class="collection-image-overlay"></div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

know this is a stupid question but I am stumped. tried moving things around. No idea why this doesnt work

Comment: What is the problem??...You have just copy-pasted some code here...who is gonna explain the problem??

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Simply putting the source (without the Liquid stuff) in [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/zrxoqxue/) shows that it does work, so the problem must be with something you're not showing.

Comment: @MathewsMathai The OP's question is in the title. Why isn't the a tag clickable?

Comment: @MathewsMathai yeah dude chill.. read the title.

Comment: @MrLister cool thanks..must be something not in that code..ill look else where

Comment: @louiepisani Don't worry.That comment was all cool.Meant no offence!